# App Inventor 2 extract numbers in JSON format

Tags: app-inventor

How to possible extract numbers in JSON format ? I found a sample but i don't know how it work. I show you here.

Sample JSON: {"out":9} {"out":76} {"out":458}

[image: JSON To TEXT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `JsonDecode` block from the `web` component to convert the JSON into a list of lists, then see the following examples how to extract your values

generally how to work with lists and list of lists:
[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

JSON and list of lists: [example1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/OGSe2a3X0fk/sVL8Adh1MHkJ) and [example2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/O5XpZEpM7zY/RlfTPifnCQAJ)
[Easy to decode large information with JSON format](https://community.thunkable.com/t/easy-to-decode-large-information-with-json-format/6132?u=taifun) by Carlos
[A general purpose JSON browser routine](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/_vk0JoHIYwI/DWikq3wGIpMJ) by ABG

Comment: Thanks for your professional answer. It was easier than I thought.